# Can I install the Exchange Management Shell on a workstation in a different forest?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, powershell

At work, we have two forests with a two-way transitive trust between them. I need access to the Exchange management shell for an Exchange environment that resides in a different forest than my workstation resides. Currently, I am logging on to one of the Exchange servers every time I need to do any maintenance.

Is it possible to install the Exchange management shell on my workstation to manage the Exchange environment in the other forest? I know the standard install instructions don't work. I'm hoping there might be another way around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to any Exchange org provided you have the proper IP connectivity to it. And you can install the Exchange Management Shell on any computer you want, even if your current forest doesn't have any Exchange servers in it.

To connect via the Exchange Management Console, just right-click on the Microsoft Exchange logo in the tree on the left and pick "Add Exchange Forest...".

To connect via the Exchange Management Shell, use the `Connect-ExchangeServer` cmdlet and specify the FQDN of one of the Exchange servers. If you use the `-User` option you can specify the username to connect with and it will prompt you for a password.

Comment: Do I need to extend the schema in the forest where my management workstation resides? I'm getting errors during the installation stating that the schema is not up to date.

Comment: I personally haven't tried. What is the exact error? Did it let you install anyway?

Comment: No, it did not let me continue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my command for connecting to any Exchange installation. Cross-forest requires you to change the authentication to basic, which in turn requires the PowerShell endpoint to be https-enabled (as far as I know).

```
function Add-Exchange2010Support
    {
        [CmdLetBinding()]
        param(
            [string]$ComputerName,
            $Creds, 
            $Authentication="Kerberos"
        )
        Write-Verbose "Connecting to Exchange Server $ComputerName"
        if ($creds)
            {
                #Exchange
                $exchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://$ComputerName/PowerShell/ -Credential $creds -AllowRedirection -Authentication $Authentication
                Import-PsSession $exchangesession
            }
        Else
            {
                $exchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://$ComputerName/PowerShell/
                Import-PsSession $exchangesession
            }

    }
```